# Breadcrumbs getting lost in odoo

Tags: odoo

There is a button in my page named 'Partner Portal Preview' in custom module in odoo. Whenever I click on the page it shows me a preview of the partner portal. Now whenever I click on back to edit mode all breadcrumbs are getting lost.

I tried debugging and found out that before I click on **Partner Portal Preview** button context looks like {'lang': 'en_US', 'tz': 'America/New_York', 'uid': 2, 'allowed_company_ids': [13], 'params': {'model': 'sale.order', 'id': 2443, 'action': 485, 'view_type': 'form', 'cids': 13}, 'active_model': 'sale.order', 'active_id': 2443, 'active_ids': [2443], 'search_default_my_orders': 1, 'search_default_not_cancelled': 1}

After I click on **Partner Portal Preview**** button and **Back to edit** context looks like {'lang': 'en_US', 'tz': 'America/New_York'}

Context is getting lost, I suspect this is the reason why breadcrumbs are getting lost

Code for partner portal preview button -

cgs.fulfillment.unit

Function of partner preview portal button -

```
def action_partner_portal_preview(self):
    cids = '%2C'.join(str(id) for id in self.env.companies.ids)
    query_string = 'fulfillment_id=%s&cids=%s&model=%s' % (self.id, cids, self._name)
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'target': 'self',
        'url': self.get_partner_portal_url(query_string=query_string)}
```

Back to edit mode functionality -

Comment: Yeah, that happens. But what's the question? How to fix it?